# how to export pdf in a4 size landscape mode using jspdf?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

I am a beginner in UI development. here, I am exporting HTML content to pdf using JSPDF library but i am facing some issues in generating pdf in a4 size landscape mode. HTML code contains data with charts(canvasjs/chartjs) and images. here, I am sharing my javascript code for generating pdf.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {    
    $('#create_pdf').click(function() {

         var HTML_Width = $("#pdfContent").width();
         var HTML_Height = $("#pdfContent").height();
         var top_left_margin = 15;
         var PDF_Width = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
         var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);
         var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
         var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;

         var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height/PDF_Height)-1;


         html2canvas($("#pdfContent")[0],{allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas) {
         canvas.getContext('2d');

         console.log(canvas.height+"  "+canvas.width);


         var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
         var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
         pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin,canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);


         for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
         pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
         pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
         }
             pdf.save("student-report.pdf");
                }); 
     });
    });
</script>
```

In above code first i have taken div data height and width and then using html2canvas used for converting html page to image added images and then converted to pdf using JSPDF.
    I expect pdf in proper a4 size landscape mode without loosing any data.I tried it but half content is splitting and I am not getting whole page content.

Comment: Try using : var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");

Comment: add tried this way but half content is splitting

Comment: Is it like content is more than the page area OR the content is less but still it's splitting into two?

Comment: actually content is not fitting in a4 size, because I have given width and height for pdf like  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);                                                                                            I calculated pdf width this way ->                                                          
 var HTML_Width = $("#pdfContent").width();
   var HTML_Height = $("#pdfContent").height();
   var top_left_margin = 15;
   var PDF_Width = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
   var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `p` by `l`

```
const PDF = new jsPDF('l', 'mm','a4')
```